# How does one "parenthesize elements"

Tags: associativity

This is probably something very obvious, but I am a little confused. It's about the associative law.

It is known that a binary structure $(S, *)$  is associative if:

$(a * b) *c = a * (b * c)$ for all elements in $S$. It's also closed, as well.

Well, say I wanted to do this with for elements in the set: $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Would parenthesizing for the associative law go something like this?

$(a * b) * c * d = a * b * (c * d) = a * (b * c) * d$ .....etc.

I know the gist of the law states that it doesn't matter which two elements you enact the operation with first, it will always be the same. But for understanding and a hw exercise, I need to know if I'm going about this correctly.

Comment: $(a*b)*c*d$ is ambiguous. $*$ is binary, so you need to know, for each $*$, what are the two operands. So $((a*b)*c)*d$ is one and $(a*b)*(c*d)$ is the other. Again, if $*$ is associative, they are equal, which you can prove from the basic associative law.

Comment: Also, so is $a\ast (b\ast (c\ast d))$

Comment: When you say ambiguous in the mathematical sense, what exactly does that mean? Are you saying it isn't very clear what things are supposed to be multiplied when I write (a * b) * c * d?

Comment: Not multiplied, I meant binary operation

Comment: oooooh Wait, nevermind. I get it! Thanks

Comment: @GrahamKemp Unclear if you mean that 'also' in reference to my comment, but your comment is not one of the ambiguous possibilities for the meaning of $(a*b)*c*d$.